# What am i doing wrong in trying to set these instance variables?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I seem to be getting something elementary wrong when trying to set and or access these variables in my `Quote` instance when i call `Quote#scrape_quote`. I can see that the values are scraped and saved to the scraped_values hash just fine, I just can't access the variables, when I call `quote.lives` for e.g. I get `nil`.

What am i getting wrong here?

quote.rb

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord 
  require 'watir'
  attr_accessor :lives, :benefit, :payment

  def scrape_quote
    rows = @browser.trs
    quote_rows = rows[1..8]
    scraped_values = {}

    quote_rows.each do |row|
      scraped_values[row.tds[0].text] = row.tds[1].text
    end

        @lives      = scraped_values[0]
        @benefit    = scraped_values[1]
        @payment    = scraped_values[2]

    puts scraped_values
  end
end
```

Comment: *I just can't access the variables* What happens if you try?

Comment: They return `nil`, sorry, I'll update above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The general case

If you just want the values of the hash sequentially assigned to member variables, you can use parallel assignment from the `hash#values` return value like this:

```
2.4.1 :001 > h = {}
 => {} 
2.4.1 :002 > h[:one] = 1
 => 1 
2.4.1 :003 > h[:two] = 2
 => 2 
2.4.1 :004 > h[:three] = 3
 => 3 
2.4.1 :005 > @one, @two, @three = h.values
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.4.1 :006 > @one
 => 1 
2.4.1 :007 > @two
 => 2 
2.4.1 :008 > @three
 => 3 
2.4.1 :009 >
```

---

## Specific application

The specific code in your case would turn into:

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord 
  require 'watir'
  attr_accessor :lives, :benefit, :payment

  def scrape_quote
    rows = @browser.trs
    quote_rows = rows[1..8]
    scraped_values = {}

    quote_rows.each do |row|
      scraped_values[row.tds[0].text] = row.tds[1].text
    end

    @lives, @benefit, @payment = scraped_values.values

    puts scraped_values
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

scraped_values is a hash not an array. You are trying to access it as if it were an array.

Use whatever is in `row.tds[0].text` to reference the hash:

```
h = {a:1,b:2}
h[:a]
=> 1
```

Comment: In particular the keys will be whatever `row.tds[0].text` returns. You should see these when you print `scraped_values`.

Comment: `scrape_quote` needs to be called to set the hash too.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to build the hash would be to use `map` instead of `each` and *do not use* upfront declarations of local variables.

```
scraped_values = quote_rows.map do |row|
  [row.tds[0].text, row.tds[1].text]
end.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `scraped_values[0]` you need something like this: `scraped_values[scraped_values.keys[0]]`, because scraped_values isn't array and 0, 1, 2 is like any other missing key, so hash returns `nil`.